# Sql Query over 3 tables with 2 many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, database

I've got 5 tables. The main tables are: `RisCtx`, `RisObj`, and `Ris`.

`RisCtx` *-----------* `RisObj` 
`RisObj` *-----------* `Ris`

(*---* = many-to-many)

So I got 2 more tables called: `RisCtxRisObj` and `RisObjRis` (for the many-to-many).

What I want is to create a `view` that collects all records from `RisCtx` which have a connection to `Ris` trough `RisObj`.

I've got kinda no clue :(.. I read something about INNER JOINs but I don't see a bit clearance...

The schema
[image: Db Schema]

```
CREATE VIEW `mydb`.`CtxView_CtxFromObj_ObjFromRisk` AS
select RisCtx.*  
from RisCtx  
inner join RisCtxRisObj on RisCtx.id=RisObjRisCtx.RisCtx_id
inner join RisObj  on RisObjRisCtx.RisObj_id=RisObj.id 
inner join RisObjRis on RisObj.id=RisObjRis.Objective_id 
inner join Ris on RisObjRis.Risk_id=Ris.id
```

Comment: Please post your schema.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the schema, and deleted some what wasn't necessary. Would it be like this? (see additional info in OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a schema, I can't show you what your `ON` clauses should look like, but the basic query structure is:

```
select RisCtx.*
from RisCtx 
inner join RisCtxRisObj on ...
inner join RisObj  on ...
inner join RisObjRis on ...
inner join Ris on ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Yes it makes sense to me finally :). I'll give it a try. And every table has an ID and the 'many-to-many'-tables have the both foreign keys of the connected tables as <tablename>_id